# fetch data from server and send back to page using MessageCenter

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to get data from server and sending back to the `xamarin form` page using `MessageCenter`

```
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Response responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(content);
if(responseData!=null)
   MessagingCenter.Send<RestApi, Response>(this, GET_DATA, responseData);
else
   MessagingCenter.Send<RestApi, Response>(this, GET_DATA, responseData);
```

and in `MainPage`  i have subscribed in as follows

```
  public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, Response>(this, RestApi.GET_DATA, (sender, arg) => {

                Debug.WriteLine("Count of data {0}", arg.data.Count);

            });


            RestApi restApi = new RestApi();
            restApi.getData();

        }


    }
```

But my control never reaches to `Debug.WriteLine("Count of data {0}", arg.data.Count);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TSender` parameter do not match between the `Subscribe` and `Publish` and thus the message is never received by your "subscribers"

Something like this would work:

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<RestApi, Response>(this, RestApi.GET_DATA, (sender, arg) => {
    Debug.WriteLine("Count of data {0}", arg.data.Count);
});
MessagingCenter.Send<RestApi, Response>(this, GET_DATA, responseData);
```

Comment: Ohh yes. Can i use interface as a TSender , so in future if my class name gets changed from RestApi to WebApi i dont have to change it everywhere , just a thought

Comment: @Hunt Interfaces work, I do this all the time `MessagingCenter.Subscribe<IMessage>(....)` &  `MessagingCenter.Send<IMessage>(....)` with an "empty" interface. Of course make sure whatever object you are passing in for the `TSender` actually implements that empty interface ;-)